# Call void function in IF statement C++

Tags: c++

*listSelectedDVD()* should display the detail when i enter the title. but in my code Im able to enter the title but didn't display details.unable to pass-in argument.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std; 

struct myStock // declare myStock fields
{
    string title;
    double price;
    int stockLevel;
    bool award;
};//end of strcut myStock

myStock list[5];

void initialize();
void listSelectedDVD(string);

int main()
{
    int choice;
    string enterTitle;

    cout << "****** MAIN MENU ******" << endl;
    cout << "1. List deatils of selected title" << endl;
    cout << "4. Exit" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "enter your choice: " << endl;
    cin >> choice;

if (choice == 1)
    {        
      cout << "Enter a Title: " << endl;
      cin >> enterTitle;
      listSelectedDVD(enterTitle);
    }
    else if (choice == 4)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    system("PAUSE");    
}//end of main
```

Here is my void Function of *void initialize()* & *void listSelectedDVD(string enterTitle)* ;

```
void initialize()
{
    list[0].title = "Ilo Ilo";
    list[0].price = 35.55;
    list[0].stockLevel = 15;
    list[0].award = true;

    list[1].title = "Money Just Enough";
    list[1].price = 10.35;
    list[1].stockLevel = 0;
    list[1].award = false;
}

void listSelectedDVD(string enterTitle)
{
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if (list[i].title.compare(enterTitle) == 0) //list[i].title == enterTitle
        {
            cout << "Title : " << list[i].title << endl;
            cout << "Price : " << list[i].price << endl;
            cout << "Stock : " << list[i].stockLevel << endl;
            cout << "Award : " << list[i].award << endl;
        }
        else { 
           out<<"Invalid Title"<<endl;
           //call back the main menu function//
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you'll have to provide the sequence of events. As of now the answer could be simply that the title doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you provide what output you are getting or is it just blank? Also are you sure the `enterTitle` is either `Ilo Ilo` or `Money Just Enough`?

Comment: ofcourse a title with spaces in name is not found when using `cin >> enterTitle;`. Use a debugger for this kind of problem, not stackoverflow

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You should first call initialize() from main before calling listSelectedDVD().

```
int main()
{
    initialize();

    //rest of your code

}//end of main
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is, when you take the user input on this line "cin >> enterTitle;", it gets the first word you typed separated by space. So when you type

**Money Just Enough**

then the value of enterTitle just becomes "**Money**".

This is the reason why your program is unable to find any match. ("Money" is not the same as "Money Just Enough")

One way to solve this is to change your code so that you can receive an entire line as a string input.

Comment: And as @user5478656 suggested, you should call initialize function inside of the main function. You defined this function and provided its prototype, but you never called it anywhere in your code.